# How to get distinct values from an array of objects which has an Array inside in on one key and count JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6, filtering

This how what array of object looks like.  `attributes__assigned_region` is a array of multiple values or it can be a single value too

```
[{
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "w",
             ],
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "x"
        ],
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "y"
        ],
        "count": 1
    },
    {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "z"
        ],
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "x",
            "z",
        ],
        "count": 2
    },
      {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "y",
            "z",
        ],
        "count": 2
    },
      {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "x",
            "y",
        ],
        "count": 4
    },
     {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "w",
            "y",
        ],
        "count": 3
    },
     {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "x",
            "y",
            "z"
        ],
        "count": 5
    },
      {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
            "x",
            "y",
            "w"
        ],
        "count": 5
    },

]
```

I want to get array of object like

```
[{
            "attributes__assigned_region": [
                "w",
               ],
            "count": 9 // the total from all count where w is avalaible (1 + 3 + 5 )
        },
        {
            "attributes__assigned_region": [
                "x"
            ],
            "count": 17 // the total from all count where y is available (1 + 2 + 4 + 5 + 5)
        },
        {
            "attributes__assigned_region": [
                "y"
            ],
            "count": 20 // the total from all count where y is available (1 + 2 + 4 + 3 + 5 + 5)
        },
        {
            "attributes__assigned_region": [
                "z"
            ],
            "count": 11 // the total from all count where y is available (2 + 2 + 2 + 5)
        }]
```

`attributes__assigned_region` needs to be a unique set and count will get added from each `attributes__assigned_region.count`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```js
let object = [{
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "w",
    ],
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "x"
    ],
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "y"
    ],
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "z"
    ],
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "x",
      "z",
    ],
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "y",
      "z",
    ],
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "x",
      "y",
    ],
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "w",
      "y",
    ],
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "x",
      "y",
      "z"
    ],
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "attributes__assigned_region": [
      "x",
      "y",
      "w"
    ],
    "count": 5
  },
]

let newObject = [];
let trackedItem = [];

object.forEach(elem => {
  elem.attributes__assigned_region.forEach(ele => {
    if (trackedItem.indexOf(ele) === -1) {
      let temObject = {
        "attributes__assigned_region": [
          ele
        ],
        "count": elem.count
      }
      trackedItem.push(ele)
      newObject.push(temObject)
    } else {
      newObject.forEach(object => {
        object.attributes__assigned_region.forEach(el => {
          if (ele === el) {
            object.count = object.count + elem.count
          }
        })
      })
    }

  })
})

console.log(newObject)
```